# Laravel 8 / Fortify - Email verification link not working (Safari)

Tags: laravel, email, laravel-8, fortify, email-verification

I'm trying to get laravel's implemented email verification system working (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/verification).

What i did so far:

1. Enabled the Feature *emailVerification* in the file **config/fortify.php** like so:

   ```
   ...

   'features' => [
       Features::registration(),
       Features::resetPasswords(),
       Features::emailVerification(),
       Features::updateProfileInformation(),
       Features::updatePasswords(),
       Features::twoFactorAuthentication([
           'confirmPassword' => true,
       ]),
   ],

   ...
   ```
2. implemented *MustVeriffyEmail* in the **app/Models/User.php** file like so:

   ```
   <?php

   namespace App\Models;

   use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
   use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
   use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
   use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
   use Laravel\Fortify\TwoFactorAuthenticatable;
   use Laravel\Jetstream\HasProfilePhoto;
   use Laravel\Jetstream\HasTeams;
   use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

   class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
   {
       use HasApiTokens;
       use HasFactory;
       use HasProfilePhoto;
       use HasTeams;
       use Notifiable;
       use TwoFactorAuthenticatable;

   ...
   ```

The result after these changes:
Everything is working just fine for Chrome or Firefox, except for Safari. If I try to click the **email verification link** which I get per mail it just redirects me to the login page (in a new tab) without any error messages. After logging in again it shows that it didn't work either. My email is now still unverified.

The link in the mail looks something like this:

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/email/verify/3/995092d93501e0759262089b7ae6eac49b6fe656?expires=1614371149&signature=66ad8a8622e89a4936c71ca89e050cfcba602d7d4dfdcaca1b430a9e5396f49f

If I check my database, everything seems fine too, except I don't get any records in the **email_verified_at** column (which is present).

Maybe someone had the same issue and could help me out here?

Best regards,
Leon

Comment: You need to log in to verify your email.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel email verification - Forced to be logged in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52949374/laravel-5-7-9-email-verification-forced-to-be-logged-in)

Comment: So far I figured out that it must be because some session details are not shared between multiple Safari tabs.... In Chrome everything works perfectly so far, in Safari only if I paste the verification link into exactly the same tab from before.... Does anyone have an idea how to work around this problem?

Comment: I do have same issue, did you find a solution?

Comment: No, sadly not yet… I just put the full verification link in the registration email to click for safari users:/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Almost two years later I now write what I found out so far:

---

## Workaround (until today):

As a workaround until today I went with a solution which is not very user-friendly.
I just put the **email-verification-link** also as plain text in the footer of my **verification-email** with a quick note for safari users to copy this link and paste it directly in the browsers url in exactly the same tab which was used before (where the user is already logged in).
This was the only solution on how I got it to work for Safari...

**The email footer looked something like this:**

[image]

---

## Today (from now on):

As I was writing this answer I went on and tested the scenario again.
I don't really know what happened in the meantime but for me it now just works as expected.
Maybe it's because I'm now using **Laravel 9** or maybe it's because I'm now using **MacOS Ventura** with **Safari Version 16.1** (18614.2.9.1.12).

---

**Please let me know if I could help you somehow and if somebody knows the answer to what happened in the meantime I'm happy to hear what it was:)**

Leon

Answer (score 2):

you are missing implements

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but i had it already in my code. Copied the wrong code for my question 
Now i updated my question... But thanks for your help!

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: @DanielGrim: It is _an_ answer. It’s no longer a _relevant_ answer because the OP has confirmed that their original code was incorrect. This answer was posted in good faith based on the original question, however.